# Python pandas - How to get a data from a column in a dataframe with the data from an other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and with a value inside the dataframe I need to get from different columns the values in the same row. In my example I need to get the value from the column Total that correspond to A1, A2 and A3. I did as following:

```
df=(['A1', 140000],['A2', 100000],['A3', 400000])
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'Total': [14000, 10000, 40000]})
CA1 = df.loc[df['A']=='A1']['Total']
CA2 = df.loc[df['A']=='A2']['Total']
CT = df.loc[df['A']=='A3']['Total']
print(CA1)
print(CA2)
print(CT)
```

but I get this result and I would need to get only the value (14000, 10000, 40000), how could I do it?
0    14000
Name: Total, dtype: int64
1    10000
Name: Total, dtype: int64
2    40000
Name: Total, dtype: int64

Comment: The result is:0    14000
Name: Total, dtype: int64
1    10000
Name: Total, dtype: int64
2    40000
Name: Total, dtype: int64

Comment: And what´s your desired result? It´s not clear.

Comment: `df['Total']` or `tuple(df['Total'])`?

Answer (score 0):

I created a data frame with an 'A4' element (to show filtering):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], 
                   'Total': [14000, 10000, 40000, 1]})
df
```

Then I converted the column 'A' to an index, selected 'A1' to (and including) 'A3', converted to a Series, and then to a list:

```
df.set_index('A').sort_index().loc['A1':'A3'].squeeze().to_list()
```

Result is:

```
[14000, 10000, 40000]
```

If you want the grand total as a scalar, change from `.squeeze().to_list()` to `.sum()`

UPDATE

You can obtain the sum like this.  The function `squeeze()` converts a data frame with 1 column to a series.  The sum of a series is a scalar.

```
scalar = df.set_index('A').sort_index().loc['A1':'A3'].squeeze().sum()
print(scalar)

64000
```

Comment: And if I only want one value, are there any way to have it? instead of a list with all the values a single value